# How to send progress message in Slackbot

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, slack-api

I have this slackbot that performs a long running task when it receives a message. I want to send an initial "Loading.." message, then if the execution time of the task is taking longer than ~15 seconds, I update the previous message to say "Still loading...".

I'm not sure how to go about the problem given my program isn't using the AsyncApp and the only solution I can think of is to use `asyncio.wait_for`

I've tried using `asyncio.wait_for(task(), timeout=15)` to update the message, but the update never executes, even if I set the timeout to 1. Also, the long_running_task() function isn't originally a coroutine, so it isn't running correctly.

```py
app = App()

async def long_running_task():
    ...

@app.event("message")
def event_message(client, event, say, logger):
    initial_message = say("Loading")
    start_message_ts = initial_message["ts"]

    async def run_task():
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(long_running_task(), timeout=15)

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await client.chat_update(
                channel=event["channel"],
                ts=start_message_ts,
                text="Still loading..."
            )

    asyncio.ensure_future(run_task())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your long task to be a sync (and not async) routine, you can just launch it in a thread, and eventually wait for it :

```py
from threading import Thread
import time

app = App()

def long_running_task():
    ...

@app.event("message")
def event_message(client, event, say, logger):
    initial_message = say("Loading")
    start_message_ts = initial_message["ts"]

    thread = Thread(target=long_running_task, daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    started = time.time()
    while thread.is_alive():
        if time.time()-started>15:
            client.chat_update(channel=event["channel"],ts=start_message_ts,text="Still loading...")
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)#Save CPU
```

(Here I did not await the `client.chat_update` for sake of simplicity, but if needed you would just launch it using asyncio)

Comment: The thread is executing correctly, but the while loop doesn't appear to be working properly. I changed the loading time from 15 to 1 and it isn't updating the message. I tried logging something within the while loop and it also isn't printing

Comment: Did you try to check/print the state of `thread.is_alive()` before the while loop ? Just to make sure that at least you enter it

Comment: It doesn't seem to run anything past thread.start(), nothing is printing when I put a print statement right after